# How to export Chrome localStorage data for a given website URL without visiting it

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, export, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

I used to have a development website : http://foo.dev

Due to recent updates on how Chrome behaves with *.dev urls (redirecting them to https (https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/), I cannot access any longer my local website.

I have changed it's url to : http://foo.local

My problem is that I would like to export the localStorage data stored from site_1 (http://foo.dev) and import it into site_2 (http://foo.local).

I know I can export the localStorage data with devTools while visiting site_1, but I cannot do that due to the redirection...

Is there a way to export the localStorage data for a website without visiting it ?

Comment: There's no API for this but I guess you can simply copy/rename the files in the browser profile directory.

Answer (score 1):

ok i solved this for my case by:

- started a web server on port 80 (actually was a spring boot app with had nothing to do with this)
- added my machine's IP to the hosts file redirecting the URL to my IP
- opened chrome on the "old URL"
- exported the LS data with LocalStorage Manager
- removed redirect in the hosts file